How to import Mermaid JS in Laravel Vite project?
This works:
@push('scripts')
    <script type="module">
        import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs'
        mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true })
    </script>
@endpush

However, I want to import the JS from my locally installed NPM package, preferably in a more global location.
I've tried import mermaid from 'mermaid' and all sorts of paths pointing to the file within node_modules, but I can't get it to work.

have you done this ? npm i mermaid , here is the doc

@francisco Of course I did. The question is how to include it in the Vite build.

does this answer?

I'm afraid not. In that example nothing is imported with the import directive, so I don't have a mermaid object to work with. Also, when I check network tab, there is no file containing mermaid being loaded. If I use the cdn version as in my original post, there are a bunch of mermaid files in network tab.
